# Not getting Scroll inside listview

Tags: android, android-listview, scrollview

I am implementing a pull to load listview. I have a listview(width and height are match parent) with one item. I can't get scroll in the empty space of the listview outside the list item. Both **onScroll** and **onScrollStateChanged** are not working in that space. It only works when scrolling in the list item. How can I get scroll in the outer space of the list item?